# MPAndroidChart LineChart for a month with only data for beginning of the month

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to build a month by month line chart with MPAndroidChart. I would like each chart to have a width set to the number of days in the month. For simplicity let's say each month is 30 days.

The problem I am encountering is in the first few days of the month I may only have a few data points. So the graph is two, three, or four days wide since that is how many data points I have for that month. I could fill in the rest of the month with 0 values but then I would end up with 0 value entries on the line chart that are in the future. It would look strange and might be confusing to users.

Is there a way to set the x-axis to 30 units while only having < 30 units of data? That way the data in the graph will fill in as the current month progresses.

Something like:

```
XAxis xaxis = chart.getXAxis();
xaxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
xaxis.setMinValue(1);
xaxis.setMaxValue(30);
xaxis.setIncrement(1);
```

The last three do not appear in the API. Is there some other way?

New with MPAndroidChart and any insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use **setAxisMaxValue** and **setAxisMinValue** which is
>   available in *com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1*

For example,

```
XAxis xaxis = chart.getXAxis();    
xaxis.setAxisMaxValue(30f);
xaxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
```

And also you can use `xaxis.mAxisRange`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you need to do is **provide a long enough x-values array** for the chart.

You want 30 days? Make your x-values array 30 entries long.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and it works sort of...so if today is June 2nd and I want a chart for June what I do for June 3rd through June 30th is put in 0 values. What happens is I wind up with 0 values through the end of the month which creates a line across the x-axis of 0 values. Wondering if it can be done with "empty" values that does not generate that line across the x-axis.